# Android JNI Crash when invoking Java Dynamic Proxy method

Tags: android, java-native-interface

For some reason, i want to invoke dynamic proxy class's method with JNI

Steps:

1. create dynamic proxy instance
2. call native method and pass the proxy instance as a parameter
3. use jni to invoke some method on proxy instance

**App code:**

```kotlin
        val target = object : ProxyTest {
            override fun testVoid() {
                Log.e(TAG, "testVoid: ")
            }

            override fun testString(): String {
                Log.e(TAG, "testString: ")
                return "hello"
            }
        }

        val proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            classLoader, arrayOf(ProxyTest::class.java)
        ) { proxy, method, args ->
            // if open code below, it will crash on all device
            // if not open, it will crash only on android 6.0, mostly on Vivo Y67
            //val myargs = args ?: emptyArray()
            //method.invoke(target, *myargs)
        } as ProxyTest
        
        invokeProxyMethod(proxy)
```

```kotlin
interface ProxyTest {
    fun testVoid()
    fun testString(): String
}
```

**Native code:**

```cpp
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_aprz_mytestdemo_jni_JNIInvokeProxyMethodActivity_invokeProxyMethod(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                            __unused     jobject thiz,
                                                                            jobject proxy) {
    jclass proxy_class = env->GetObjectClass(proxy);
//    jmethodID test_void_method_id = env->GetMethodID(proxy_class, "testString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jmethodID test_void_method_id = env->GetMethodID(proxy_class, "testVoid", "()V");
    LOGD("jmethodId = %d", test_void_method_id == nullptr);
    jvalue *args = {};
    jobject obj = env->NewLocalRef(proxy);
    env->CallVoidMethodA(obj, test_void_method_id, args);
}
```

Comment: Creating a new local ref from `activity` and `proxy` is useless: they are passed into your function so they are already local refs.

Comment: I know, you can ignore these useless code.

Comment: Where is your error checking? You don't check if `FindClass` or `GetMethodID` returned sane values, or if there are any pending Java exceptions.

Comment: Also, what is `Proxy`? And what is this code supposed to do? The fact that you're explicitly creating new `Activity` instances is pretty odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in android M preview, commit id : f015c2f4835a9985a8b31cfc810129b69865a6c4.

Also, there some more bug in android JNI.
For example,:

> [check_jni.cc](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:art/runtime/jni/check_jni.cc;l=1796;bpv=1;bpt=1?q=checkjni&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject)

```cpp
bool CheckMethodAndSig(ScopedObjectAccess& soa, jobject jobj, jclass jc,
                         jmethodID mid, Primitive::Type type, InvokeType invoke)
{
...
// **this should be m->GetInterfaceMethodIfProxy(xx)->GetShorty(xxx);**
if (type != Primitive::GetType(m->GetShorty()[0])) {
...
}
```